# How to read and write to NFC tags in NDEF format using C# compatible with Android?

Tags: c#, wpf, format, nfc, ndef

I am working with [Mifare Ultralight C](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ICU1.pdf) tags and write data in NDEF format to them. Am using [NDEF-NFC library](https://github.com/andijakl/ndef-nfc) to create raw bytes for my NDEF message. My NDEF message is

```
var spRecord = new NdefTextRecord {
        Text = "1",
        LanguageCode = "en"
};
var msg = new NdefMessage { spRecord };
```

The output I get is `D1 01 04 54 02 65 6E 31` (hexadecimal). If I write this byte array to the tag as-is:

- After reading from the tag and using the same NDEF-NFC library I am able to convert back to the desired NDEF message.
- Android applications do not recognize the NDEF message. I tried [NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc) for Android.

Following the suggestions in *[Writing Ndef to NFC tag in Windows Form Application C# using ACR122U as Reader/Writer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33760653/2425802)*, I modified my byte array to write `03 08 D1 01 04 54 02 65 6E 31 FE 00` instead of the original byte array produced by the library.

- Now I'm able to read the NDEF message using Android apps.
- But on trying to convert the byte array to an NDEF message object using the library, I get the following error:

  > Ndef parse error: Expected Message Begin missing in first record.

How can I read back the NDEF message correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already found, NFC Forum Type 2 tags (such as MIFARE Ultralight, NTAG, etc.) require an NDEF message to be embedded into a NDEF TLV (tag-length-value) structure. This means that you prepend the tag `03` and the length of the NDEF message to the message (value) itself. Thus, you get

```
+-----+--------+-------------------------+
| TAG | LENGTH | VALUE                   |
| 03  | 08     | D1 01 04 54 02 65 6E 31 |
+-----+--------+-------------------------+
```

In addition you may add a Terminator TLV (tag = `FE`, length = `00`) to indicate that the remaining data area on the tag can be skipped from processing.

The NDEF library that you use only processes **NDEF messages** and not the container format that is needed for storing the data on an NFC tag. Thus, you need to process that part yourself.

#### Pack NDEF message into TLV structure

```
var msg = new NdefMessage { ... };
var msgBytes = msg.toByteArray();
var ndefTlvLen = new byte[(msgBytes.Length < 255) ? 1 : 3];
if (msgBytes.Length < 255) {
    ndefTlvLen[0] = (byte)(msgBytes.Length);
} else {
    ndefTlvLen[0] = (byte)0x0FF;
    ndefTlvLen[1] = (byte)((msgBytes.Length >> 8) & 0x0FF);
    ndefTlvLen[2] = (byte)(msgBytes.Length & 0x0FF);
}
var tagData = new byte[1 + ndefTlvLen.Length + msgBytes.Length + 2];
int offset = 0;
tagData[offset++] = (byte)0x003;
Array.Copy(ndefTlvLen, 0, tagData, offset, ndefTlvLen.Length);
offset += ndefTlvLen.Length;
Array.Copy(msgBytes, 0, tagData, offset, msgBytes.Length);
offset += msgBytes.Length;
tagData[offset++] = (byte)0x0FE;
tagData[offset++] = (byte)0x000;
```

#### Unpack NDEF message from TLV structure

```
var tagData = ...; // byte[]
var msg;
int offset = 0;
while (offset < tagData.Length) {
    byte tag = tagData[offset++];
    int len = (tagData[offset++] & 0x0FF);
    if (len == 255) {
        len = ((tagData[offset++] & 0x0FF) << 8);
        len |= (tagData[offset++] & 0x0FF);
    }
    if (tag == (byte)0x03) {
        var msgBytes = new byte[len];
        Array.Copy(tagData, offset, msgBytes, 0, len);
        msg = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(msgBytes);
    } else if (tag == (byte)0xFE) {
        break;
    }
    offset += len;
}
```