# Xamarin Android NDEF Format ISO 15693 NFC Tag

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

[image: Scanned Tag]

Hi,
   I have a requirement to NDEF format an ISO 15693 NFC Tag. The tag in the image has been NDEF formatted using NXP tools and a Text Guid written to the tag by my application. I would like my application to also be able to format the tag if required but have been unable to find any information on how this is achieved.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Paul.

Comment: If you want to use NDFF to read and write NFC tag, you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359491/how-to-read-and-write-to-nfc-tags-in-ndef-format-using-c-sharp-compatible-with-a and https://www.patrickvankleef.com/2017/01/08/xamarin-near-field-communication/

Comment: Cherry Bu,
                  Thanks for the reply. I have seen both the links previously. I don't believe they are suitable for the NfcV type tags I am using.

Regards
Paul

Answer (score -1):

After much testing of flags etc I eventually found the below code works.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {

        try
        {

            if (inWriteMode)
            {

                inWriteMode = false;

                Tag tag = intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;

                byte[] id = tag.GetId();

                NfcV nfcvTag = NfcV.Get(tag);

                int[] intArray = new int[36];

                // 4d196b8c-aa42-4f90-924f-b953654c31f7 (Length = 36)
                string guidStr = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                char[] guidChars = guidStr.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < guidChars.Count(); i++)
                {
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(guidChars[i]);
                    intArray[i] = value;
                }

                if (nfcvTag != null)
                {

                    nfcvTag.Connect();

                    // 0x20 with id (UID) works! (addressed v non addressed using 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // E1 40 0E 00
                    byte[] cmd0 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20, // 0x00 0x20 0x22 0x40 0x42 ????
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x00,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)0xE1, (byte)0x40, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x00
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd0, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // 03 2B D1 01
                    byte[] cmd1 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x01,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)0x03, (byte)0x2B, (byte)0xD1, (byte)0x01
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd1, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // 27 54 02 65
                    byte[] cmd2 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x02,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)0x27, (byte)0x54, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x65
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd2, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // 6E XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd3 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x03,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)0x6E, (byte)intArray[0], (byte)intArray[1], (byte)intArray[2]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd3, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd4 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x04,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[3], (byte)intArray[4], (byte)intArray[5], (byte)intArray[6]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd4, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd5 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x05,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[7], (byte)intArray[8], (byte)intArray[9], (byte)intArray[10]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd5, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd6 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x06,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[11], (byte)intArray[12], (byte)intArray[13], (byte)intArray[14]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd6, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd7 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x07,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[15], (byte)intArray[16], (byte)intArray[17], (byte)intArray[18]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd7, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd8 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x08,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[19], (byte)intArray[20], (byte)intArray[21], (byte)intArray[22]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd8, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd9 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x09,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[23], (byte)intArray[24], (byte)intArray[25], (byte)intArray[26]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd9, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd10 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x0A,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[27], (byte)intArray[28], (byte)intArray[29], (byte)intArray[30]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd10, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd11 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x0B,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[31], (byte)intArray[32], (byte)intArray[33], (byte)intArray[34]
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd11, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // XX XX XX XX
                    byte[] cmd12 = new byte[] {
                    /* FLAGS   */ (byte)0x20,
                    /* COMMAND */ (byte)0x21,
                    /* UID     */ (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                    /* OFFSET  */ (byte)0x0C,
                    /* DATA    */ (byte)intArray[35], (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00
                    };

                    Array.Copy(id, 0, cmd12, 2, 8);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    byte[] response0 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd0);
                    byte[] response1 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd1);
                    byte[] response2 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd2);
                    byte[] response3 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd3);
                    byte[] response4 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd4);
                    byte[] response5 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd5);
                    byte[] response6 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd6);
                    byte[] response7 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd7);
                    byte[] response8 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd8);
                    byte[] response9 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd9);
                    byte[] response10 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd10);
                    byte[] response11 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd11);
                    byte[] response12 = nfcvTag.Transceive(cmd12);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    nfcvTag.Close();

                }

                DisplayMessage("Guid (" + guidStr + ") written to tag.");

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayMessage("Exception - " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```