# Trouble writing NDEF record to NTAG213 using external NFC reader (but writing to memory works)

Tags: nfc, mifare, ndef, acr122, smartcardio

I am using the sample provided by Michael Roland in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105626/writing-ndef-data-to-ntag216-tag-using-low-level-nfc-communication-methods) and modified the bytes command structure to match [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760653/writing-ndef-to-nfc-tag-in-windows-form-application-c-sharp-using-acr122u-as-rea).

After I scan the tag, I receive `90 00` responses from the reader. When I then scan the tag using NFC Tools though, I don't see that it has an NDEF record ([photo](https://photos.app.goo.gl/nZ9kBWrn7J8x5ZLw8)). If I examine the memory I can see my data written starting at block 4 as follows [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/SLqJUTotwWNnTzv4A).

Meanwhile, if I use the Write Tag feature of NFC Tools to write an NDEF message and then scan the tag again, [it does work](https://photos.app.goo.gl/9PZSTRMcdwQofjkT7). The memory in the blocks other than those starting at block 4 appear to be identical ([photo](https://photos.app.goo.gl/tnng5E7SZNTd73Jj6)).

I don't believe it's a capability container issue as the memory is identical in block 3 after writing to the tag from my reader vs. NFC Tools.

Do I need to do any other kind of NDEF read / check command prior to writing to block 4?

My code below:

```
                         byte[] ndefMessage = new byte[] {
                                (byte)0xD1, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x0C, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x63, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x2F
                        };

                        // wrap into TLV structure
                        byte[] tlvEncodedData = null;
                        Log.e("length",String.valueOf(ndefMessage.length));
                        if (ndefMessage.length < 255) {
                            tlvEncodedData = new byte[ndefMessage.length + 3];
                            tlvEncodedData[0] = (byte)0x03;  // NDEF TLV tag
                            tlvEncodedData[1] = (byte)(ndefMessage.length & 0x0FF);  // NDEF TLV length (1 byte)
                            System.arraycopy(ndefMessage, 0, tlvEncodedData, 2, ndefMessage.length);
                            tlvEncodedData[2 + ndefMessage.length] = (byte)0xFE;  // Terminator TLV tag
                        } else {
                            tlvEncodedData = new byte[ndefMessage.length + 5];
                            tlvEncodedData[0] = (byte)0x03;  // NDEF TLV tag
                            tlvEncodedData[1] = (byte)0xFF;  // NDEF TLV length (3 byte, marker)
                            tlvEncodedData[2] = (byte)((ndefMessage.length >>> 8) & 0x0FF);  // NDEF TLV length (3 byte, hi)
                            tlvEncodedData[3] = (byte)(ndefMessage.length & 0x0FF);          // NDEF TLV length (3 byte, lo)
                            System.arraycopy(ndefMessage, 0, tlvEncodedData, 4, ndefMessage.length);
                            tlvEncodedData[4 + ndefMessage.length] = (byte)0xFE;  // Terminator TLV tag
                        }

                        // fill up with zeros to block boundary:
                        tlvEncodedData = Arrays.copyOf(tlvEncodedData, (tlvEncodedData.length / 4 + 1) * 4);

                        for (int i = 0; i < tlvEncodedData.length; i += 4) {
                            byte[] command = new byte[] {
                                    (byte)0xFF, // WRITE
                                    (byte)0xD6,
                                    (byte)0x00,
                                    (byte)((4 + i / 4) & 0x0FF), // block address
                                    (byte)0x04,
                                    0, 0, 0, 0
                            };

                            System.arraycopy(tlvEncodedData, i, command, 5, 4);

                            ResponseAPDU answer = cardChannel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(command));
                            byte[] response = answer.getBytes();
                            writeLogWindow("response: "+ byteArrayToHexString(response));
                        }
```

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text in a question, it makes it so difficult to understand and work with. NFC Tools allows you to export the memory read as text, so it can be added to the question as text (and please make sure it is nicely formatted)

Comment: Sorry about that, noted for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that Michael Roland's answer has a bug in it.

`D1 01 0C 55 01 65 78 61 6D 70 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D 2F` is not a valid Ndef message.

If you look at the various specs for Ndef at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/tree/master/docs (specifically the NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf and NFCForum-TS-NDEF_1.0.pdf) his example of "http://www.example.com/" is actually made up of "http://www." which has a type code of `01` and 12 characters or the rest of the URL.

Thus the payload length is 13 (1 + 12) bytes so `OD` where as his message:-

D1 01 **0C** 55 01 65 78 61 6D 70 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D 2F

only specifies the length of the second part of the URL and not the prefix, so is one byte too short.

This is confirmed if you try and write a record for that URL using the NFC Tools App or NXP's TagWriter App both generate a message of

`D1 01 0D 55 01 65 78 61 6D 70 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D 2F`

So try using in your code

```
byte[] ndefMessage = new byte[] {
    (byte)0xD1, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x0D, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x78,
    (byte)0x61, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x70, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x63,
    (byte)0x6F, (byte)0x6D, (byte)0x2F
};
```